# How do I plot a bar_plot with facet_wrap function in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-wrap

I am trying to plot a bar chart for the most frequented words yearwise but the ggplot plots only one graph

```
word frequency Year
easy use                            easy use         9 2019
value money                      value money         8 2019
project management        project management         4 2019
business management      business management         3 2019
customer serviceâ€\u009d customer serviceâ€\u009d    3 2019
everything need              everything need         3 2019

tail(unified)


word frequency Year
workflows support workflows support         1 2014
working people       working people         1 2014
works helpful         works helpful         1 2014
worth try1                worth try         1 2014
write invoices       write invoices         1 2014
years research       years research         1 2014




ggplot(head(unified,25), aes(reorder(word,-frequency), frequency)) +  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~Year) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +  xlab("Bigrams") + ylab("Frequency") +
  ggtitle("Most frequent bigrams for all years")
```

My ggplot generates only the bar plot for 2019. Please help

Comment: Did you mean to put `head(unified,25)` into `ggplot`? It's possible `ggplot` is only reading the first 25 rows.

Comment: Yes, I need only the top 25 entries

Comment: I think you want something like `library(dplyr); dplyr::group_by(unified, Year) %>% dplyr::top_n(25, frequency)` as input to the `data` argument of `ggplot`

Comment: I would like to plot a bar graph for the top 25 words against their corresponding frequencies across all the years

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::top_n` to select to top 25 most frequent words by year.

```r
library(tidyverse)

n <- 1000
t <- 4

unified <- data.frame(
    word = sample(letters[1:8], n * t, replace = TRUE),
    Year = sort(rep(1:t, n))
  ) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Year) %>%
  dplyr::count(word, name = "frequency") %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Year, desc(frequency)) %>%
  dplyr::top_n(25, frequency) %>%
  dplyr::select(word, frequency, Year) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()


ggplot(unified, aes(reorder(word, -frequency), frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Year, scales="free") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  xlab("Bigrams") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  ggtitle("Most frequent bigrams for all years")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>